# Webservice with firebird and php

Tags: php, firebird

I have to make a webservice with PHP that connects to a Firebird database (.gbd extension), and that I will later read from an Android Studio project. It's the first time I work with Firebird databases and it's not working well for me. This is my PHP code:

```
<?php 

$str_conn = "firebird:dbname=C:\Temporal\POLICLINICA.GDB;host=localhost";   

$dbh = new PDO($str_conn, "SYSDBA", "masterkey");

$res=$dbh->query("select NOMBRE from GES_PERSONAL");

$datos = array();

foreach ($res as $row) {
    $datos[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($datos);

?>
```

But when I check it in my web browser, it does not return anything. White screen.

However, if I pass a `print_r($datos)`, it does return an array.

```
     Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
   [NOMBRE] => ISABEL SANCHEZ VALERA
        [0] => ISABEL SANCHEZ VALERA ) 
        [1] => Array ( [NOMBRE] => ADRIAN TORRES GINER  [0] => ADRIAN TORRES GINER  ) 
        [3] => Array ( [NOMBRE] => ANTONIO JOSE PARRA MARTINEZ [0] => ANTONIO JOSE PARRA MARTINEZ )
        [5] => Array ( [NOMBRE] => ROSA ANA MELLADO MARTINEZ [0] => ROSA ANA MELLADO MARTINEZ ) 
        [6] => Array ( [NOMBRE] => JOSE ANTONIO MARTIN ORTEGA [0] => JOSE ANTONIO MARTIN ORTEGA ) 
     ) 
)
```

In MySQL, when I pass a `json_encode($datos)` without `print_r()` the webservice send me a JSON, but apparently in Firebird it doesn't. Why is that and how can I fix this?

Comment: Solved! I answer in case someone else has the same problem.

In the firebird connection, the charset parameter is required.

I fixed it by adding the charset parameter to the end of the connection line:

$str_conn = "firebird:dbname = C:\Temporal\POLICLINICA.GDB;host=localhost; **charset=UTF8"**;

Comment: Consider posting an answer with your solution, and accepting it after the time out. That will give better visibility than a comment. However, Firebird **does not** require a connection character set. If no character set is specified it will default to character set `NONE` which essentially returns string data as stored, this may then lead to conversion issues later (which may be your actual problem, not sure about that).